# Convert this json string to java object

Tags: java, json

I need to convert this json string to java object

```
{"status":"success","result":{"123":{"status":"success","result":{"msisdn":"123","latestStatusId":8,"predictedIABCategoryCount":{"2":47,"5":4,"6":4,"444":4}},{"456":{"status":"success","result":{"msisdn":"456","latestStatusId":8,"predictedIABCategoryCount":{"2":47,"5":4,"6":4,"444":4}}}
```

please help because it seems to be complex string

Comment: Use GSON or Jackson library

Comment: I already use gson and jackon and converted more strings but this string is more complex and i failed to convert it

Comment: so where is you code that failed? please post it here.

Comment: please write for me the java object(nested java class) for this json string

Comment: It's not a valid JSON. please validate [here](http://jsonlint.com/) and post valid one.